# How to? Rails arrange posts randomly with previous/next view depending on tag_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

So I want to have a link on my rails app which links to a **view** that shows a **random question** of a **certain tag_id**

The use case is a quiz app for my class, and we have N number of tags, with N questions. Each question can have multiple tags.

I want to have a way to be able to **randomly display (read: no person should have the same order of questions)**, but still be able to do **all the questions** that have a certain **tag_id** by clicking previous/next in a view.

I figured out how to display all the questions of a certain tag in a view, but I'm still having trouble how to show previous/next randomly for a certain tag. Ex: When a user clicks on a link, it should randomly generate or list all the questions for the **tag_id** and only be accessible in that view for that **tag_id**. Everyone will do the same questions, just not in the same order.

I realize there are gems out there, but I want to learn and understand how it's done from scratch first.

questions/show.html.erb

```
<strong>tags</strong><br>
<%= @question.tags.map{|t| t.name}.join(", ") %>

<%= link_to "Previous Question", @question.previous %>
<%= link_to "Next Question", @question.next %>
```

Here's my questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @question = Question.new
    end

def index
    if params[:tag_id].present?
        tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
        @questions = tag.questions
    else
        @questions = Question.all
    end
end

    def show
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])  

    end    etc etc ... [rest of code here is redacted as its not relevant]
end
```

Here's my question.rb model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

    #links this to the user.rb model?
    belongs_to :user

    scope :next, lambda {|id| where("id > ?",id).order("id ASC") } # this is the default ordering for AR
    scope :previous, lambda {|id| where("id < ?",id).order("id DESC") }

    def next
      Question.next(self.id).first
    end

    def previous
      Question.previous(self.id).first
    end
end
```

tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :questions, through: :taggings # notice the use of the plural model name
end
```

tagging.rb

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question  # foreign key - post_id
  belongs_to :tag   # foreign key - tag_id
end
```

Comment: You will have to store the generated random order for each user (e.g. in a database, perhaps the session or the cookie). Otherwise, you cannot remember which questions the visitor already saw or still needs to see on following requests. In other words, you can generate another random order for each visitor, but once generated for a user that order needs to be stable for that user.

Comment: If your have only a view records and its unlikly that new recorda are added, then you can use `#permutation` method over all ids.You choose randomly one of the permutation and store the index of the chosen permutation plus the current position in this array. Other wise choose @spickermann answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Array#shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) method and seed it with the `id` of the `current_user`. Something like this.

```
@questions = Question.next.shuffle(random: Random.new(current_user.id))
@questions = Question.prev.shuffle(random: Random.new(current_user.id))
@questions = tag.questions.shuffle(random: Random.new(current_user.id))
```

That way the order will be the same for that user even with multiple page refreshes. And there will be a different order for each user.